# python seaborn: customize line plot and scatterplot together (also legend)

Tags: python, data-visualization, seaborn

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
           'id': {0: -3, 1: 2, 2: -3, 3: 1},
           'val': {0: 0.4, 1: 0.03, 2: 0.88, 3: 1.3},
           'indicator': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'B'},
           'count': {0: 40000, 1: 5779, 2: 3000, 3: 31090}
          })
df
```

and I hope to get a plot like the following:
[image]

I know with code of following, I can get a close plot but I want to have the line size also varies with "count" variable, but when I tried to add size = 'count', I did not get a meaningful plot and also for the legend, I want to only have one legend for "indicator" rather than two:

```
plt.figure()
sns.lineplot(x = 'id', y = 'val', hue = 'indicator', data = df)
sns.scatterplot(x = 'id', y = 'val', hue = 'indicator', size = 'count', data = df)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the second part of your question - you can disable the lineplot legend like so:

```
sns.lineplot(x = 'id', y = 'val', hue = 'indicator', data = df, legend=False)
```

This will leave you with two legend groups - one for colours and one for sizes. This is the easiest way, but you can also tinker with `plt.legend()` and build your own from scratch.

As for making the lines vary their thickness dynamically from one point to another, I don't think you can do it using seaborn. For something like that you'd need a more low-level library, like bokeh or use matplotlib directly to draw connecting lines between line markers, adjusting for their varying size.